# Parse long CSV file with esp8266

Tags: esp8266, sd-card, gps, nodemcu

I'm trying to write a code for nodeMCU (esp8266 based board) to continuously calculate distance between GPS location and geographical coordinates written in a CSV file in SD. Originally I thought the best way to do it was to parse the file, save the longitudes and latitudes in two arrays at startup and, then, calculate continuously distances between arrays and coordinates taken from GPS. If distance is less than a value, an output warns me. There is only a "little" problem: the file contains 5500 coordinates and, so, it is impossible to allocate two arrays containing 5500 floats inside ram memory. Now I have thought two alternatives: 
1) save the two arrays in flash memory that is, I know, a lot slower but also bigger
2) parse and calculate distance line by line continuously: in a loop I'll take the first line from SD, parse it, calculate distance between it and GPS location and, then do the same thing for second, third,... line. It requires the continuous access to SD and parsing but I don't have to use flash memory.
What is the best option in your opinion? Have you got alternatives or suggestions?
Thank you!!

Comment: I vote for 1). Is SD card faster then flash? Why not use file with SPIFFS?

Comment: I don't know if SD is faster than flash; probably it is. I have never used spiffs so I am a little bit scared on how to use it. Have you got suggestions?

Comment: Can I only save .txt files inside SPIFFS or also arrays? If I save, for example, a .txt file with coordinates, I need to reopen it and parse it again, will it be convenient? Maybe I can use option 2 with SPIFFS instead of with SD

Comment: I moved the comments to an answer

Comment: use an ESP32 instead: ~6X the usable RAM of the 8266

Comment: @dandavis at the end I decided to save file in SPIFFS, parse line by line and calculate distance line by line. It only takes 6 seconds at 160MHz; it's acceptable for what I want to do. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead od the SD card you can use the esp8266 file system SPIFFS. It uses the flash of the esp8266, which is connected at 40MHz as Quad I/O on newer systems.

To [use SPIFFS](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/filesystem.rst) you create a folder named `data` in your esp8266 sketch folder. You put the files in that folder and then you use the SPIFFS upload plugin.

In runtime use the SPIFFS library. It is similar to SD library.